# How to show record in table using JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I have one JSON file. I have to read JSON file in this file **WinType** is field in that field two value **Nominated** and **Win**. I have to arrange this value into table as in `1 = Win` and `0 = Nominated`. So my table is shows as follows

```
<html>
    <body>
        <TABLE BORDER=2 BORDERCOLOR=RED> 
            <TR> 
                <TD>12 Years a Slave</TD>
                <TD>1</TD>
                <TD>1</TD>
                <TD>0</TD>
            </TR>

            <TR> 
                <TD>American Hustle</TD>
                <TD>0</TD>
                <TD>0</TD>
                <TD>1</TD>
            </TR> 

            <TR> 
                <TD>Captain Phillips</TD>
                <TD>0</TD>
                <TD>0</TD>
                <TD>1</TD>
            </TR>
        </TABLE>
    </body>
</html>
```

My JSON file is:

```
   [
    {
        "ID":1, "Nominee":"12 Years a Slave", "WinProbability":0.00, "WinType":"Win"
    },
    {
        "ID":2, "Nominee":"12 Years a Slave", "WinProbability":2.81, "WinType":"Win"
    },
    {   
        "ID":3, "Nominee":"12 Years a Slave", "WinProbability":0.66, "WinType":"Nominated"
    },
    {   
        "ID":1, "Nominee":"American Hustle", "WinProbability":1.62, "WinType":"Nominated"
    },
    {
        "ID":2, "Nominee":"American Hustle", "WinProbability":0.85, "WinType":"Win"
    },
    {
        "ID":3, "Nominee":"American Hustle", "WinProbability":0.07, "WinType":"Win"
    },
    {   
        "ID":1, "Nominee":"Captain Phillips", "WinProbability":2.70,  "WinType":"Nominated"
    },
    {
        "ID":2, "Nominee":"Captain Phillips", "WinProbability":0.00, "WinType":"Win"
    },
    {   
        "ID":3, "Nominee":"Captain Phillips", "WinProbability":1.52, "WinType":"Win"
    }
]
```

I tried to but not working properly.

Tried code

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'movie.json',
    dataType:'json',

    success:function(data)
    {
        var items=data;
        var lookup={};
        var result=[];
        for(var item,i=0;item=items[i++];)
        {
            var movie=item.Nominee;
            console.log(movie);
            if(!(movie in lookup))
            {
                lookup[movie]=1;
                result.push(movie);
            }
        }
        result.sort();
        console.log(result);

        $("#table").click(function(){
            alert("Fasdfasd");
            var hii=0;
            var goo=1;

            for( var j=0;j<=result.length;j++)
            {
                $('#Table').append('<tr><td>'+result[j]+'<td>');
                for(var k=0;k<10;k++)
                {
                    alert(items[k]['ID']);
                    alert(items[k]['Nominee']);
                    alert(items[k]['WinType']);
                    if(items[k]['Nominee']==result[j] && items[k]['WinType']=="Win" ) {     
                        $('#Table').append('<td>'+hii+'</td>');
                    } else {
                        $('#Table').append('<td>'+goo+'</td>');
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            $('#Table').append('</tr>');
        });
```

Please suggest me how to solve this.

Comment: *"I tried to but not working properly"* - Where's your JS? What actually happened when you ran it?

Comment: you should us javaScript to init the json

Comment: First of your table does not have any id `#table", second you declare it differntly `#table` and `#Table`. Start with correcting that.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38681756/747579) works fine .. Hope it is useful unless i will delete to avoid vote-dwon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to **GROUP_BY** your JSON data by `Nominee` BEFORE.

## [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/4vg2broh/)  :

---

## Live DEMO :

```js
var data=[{"ID":1,"Nominee":"12 Years a Slave","WinProbability":0.00,"WinType":"Win"},{"ID":2,"Nominee":"12 Years a Slave","WinProbability":2.81,"WinType":"Win"},{"ID":3,"Nominee":"12 Years a Slave","WinProbability":0.66,"WinType":"Nominated"},{"ID":1,"Nominee":"American Hustle","WinProbability":1.62,"WinType":"Nominated"},{"ID":2,"Nominee":"American Hustle","WinProbability":0.85,"WinType":"Win"},{"ID":3,"Nominee":"American Hustle","WinProbability":0.07,"WinType":"Win"},{"ID":1,"Nominee":"Captain Phillips","WinProbability":2.70,"WinType":"Nominated"},{"ID":2,"Nominee":"Captain Phillips","WinProbability":0.00,"WinType":"Win"},{"ID":3,"Nominee":"Captain Phillips","WinProbability":1.52,"WinType":"Win"}];


var groupByNominee=data.reduce(function(rv, x) {
    (rv[x['Nominee']] = rv[x['Nominee']] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
  }, {});
var html=Object.keys(groupByNominee).map((nom)=>
          `<TR> 
                    <TD>${nom}</TD>
                     ${groupByNominee[nom].map((item)=>`\t<TD>${(item.WinType==='Win')?1:0}</TD>`).join('\t\n')}

               </TR>`
    
          
    ).join('\n');

$(html).appendTo('#Table');
 console.log(html);
//console.log(groupByNominee);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="Table"></table>
```

---

## Explain :

- Group `data`(**array**) by `Nominee` & save ouput in `groupByNominee` (**object of arrays**) :

  ---> if `data=[{ID:1,Nominee:'A',WinType:'W'},{ID:2,Nominee:'B',WinType:'W'},{ID:1,Nominee:'A',WinType:'N'}]`

  ---> `groupByNominee` will be `={'A':[ID:1,Nominee:'A',WinType:'W'},{ID:1,Nominee:'A',WinType:'N'}],'B':[{ID:2,Nominee:'B',WinType:'W'}]}`
- Loop through `Nominee` (`groubByNominee`) object & for each iteration

  - Build `<TD>${Nominee}</TD>`
  - Loop through Array of current Nominee and append `<TD>WinType?0:1</TD>`
  - Join all string. `html="<TD>...<TD>...</TD>...</TD>"`
  - Wrap this string by jQuery `$(html)` & append it to `Table`.

Comment: suppose in my json file first movie has 3 records and second movie have 1 and 3 records and 2 record miss so i want 2 <td></td> blank can you suggest how can i do this